# How to prevent dequeued collection view cells from overlapping each other?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been trying to set up a collection view where I have the user submit several strings which I toss in an array and call back through the collection view's cellForItemAt function. However, whenever I add a row to to the top of the collection view, it adds the cell label literally on top of the last cell label so  [they stack like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeY1X.png). Notice how every new word I add includes all the other previous words in the rendering.

The code I have at cellForItemAt is

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InterestsCell", for: indexPath) as? InterestsCell {
        cell.interestLabel.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

and the code I have when the add button is pressed is

```
func addTapped() {
    let interest = interestsField.text
    array.insert(interest!, at: 0)
    interestsField.text = ""

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I looked everywhere and tried to use prepareForReuse() but it didn't seem to work. I later tried deleting cells by calling didSelect and the cells would not disappear again. Any help is appreciated!

[This is the code I have in my custom collection view cell implementation in the event that this is causing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk9Vv.png)

Comment: I'd suggest using the view debugger to identify what the issue is (e.g. overlapping labels, overlapping cells, or overlapping collection views). One you know what the view hierarchy looks like, that will narrow down your research.

Comment: @Rob Thanks Rob, that put me on the right track. For some reason it's creating a new instance of a collection view every single time I add a new string so it stacks each collection on top of each other.

Comment: yep, now you can track down where you’re adding the duplicative collection view. But it’s not in the code that you’ve shared with us thus far. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not include the code necessary to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

To do this paste these functions in your project

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}
```

you can play around with the values :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily implemented using UITableView. So try to use UITableView instead of UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding a new label every time you set the text. If you want to lazily load the UILabel you need to add `lazy`

```
lazy var interestLabel: UILabel = {
  ...
}()
```

I wouldn't do it this way though, I would create a reference to the label

```
weak var interestLabel: UILabel!
```

Then add the label in your setupViews method

```
func setupViews() {
    ...
    let interestLabel = UILabel()
    ...
    contentView.addSubview(interestLabel)
    self.interestLabel = interestLabel
}
```